# Unlisted Open Beta on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Looking at the [documentation here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

On Google Play, when you create an open beta:

> Users can find your open test via search on Google Play. Once users find your listing, they can install your app normally.

This is not the behavior we want for our open beta. We don't want the app to be discoverable by searching the store. We only want the app only to be accessible by a link. This is possible using iOS's TestFlight platform.

We don't want a closed alpha because we don't want to manage a list of emails. We'd like anyone with the link to have access.

Is there any way to make a "link-only" open beta in Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't. However, you might be interested in creating an alpha test, instead of using mails, using a Google Group.

Reference in [*Closed test: manage testers with Google Groups*](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en).